# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in Javascript (geolocation)

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, geolocation

I am getting the Javascript error "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" when running the code

```
var nativeGeoloation = window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition;
nativeGeoloation(function (){ alert("ok")});
```

I have tried calling the code in the context of the window, but get the same error:

```
nativeGeoloation.call(window,function (){ alert("ok")})
```

The background of this question is that I am trying to access the native version of the geolocation function that has been overwritten by another javascript library (cordova)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error I'm getting in Firefox is:

> TypeError: 'getCurrentPosition' called on an object that does not implement interface Geolocation.

Change your code to:

```
var nativeGeoloation = window.navigator.geolocation;
nativeGeoloation.getCurrentPosition(function (){ alert("ok")});
```

(Note, you've also spelled `nativeGeoloation` incorrectly which might cause you problems down the road if you start to spell it correctly).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1fdd22wr/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!, that was quick. Although I do feel a little dyslexic now :)